# React Slick Slider href always points to the same link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, gatsby, react-slick

I have the following slider

```
 const Slides = () => {
      const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
      query Slider {
        allPrismicSlider {
          nodes {
            data {
              slider {
                alternative_text
                image {
                  url
                }
                link {
                  slug
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }      
      `)

      const slides = [
        {
          uid: data.allPrismicSlider.nodes[0].data.slider[0].link.slug,
          url: data.allPrismicSlider.nodes[0].data.slider[0].link.slug,
          src: data.allPrismicSlider.nodes[0].data.slider[0].image.url,
          alt: data.allPrismicSlider.nodes[0].data.slider[0].alternative_text,
        },
        {
          uid: data.allPrismicSlider.nodes[0].data.slider[1].link.slug,
          url: data.allPrismicSlider.nodes[0].data.slider[1].link.slug,
          src: data.allPrismicSlider.nodes[0].data.slider[1].image.url,
          alt: data.allPrismicSlider.nodes[0].data.slider[1].alternative_text,
        },
        {
          uid: data.allPrismicSlider.nodes[0].data.slider[2].link.slug,
          url: data.allPrismicSlider.nodes[0].data.slider[2].link.slug,
          src: data.allPrismicSlider.nodes[0].data.slider[2].image.url,
          alt: data.allPrismicSlider.nodes[0].data.slider[2].alternative_text,
        },
        {
          uid: data.allPrismicSlider.nodes[0].data.slider[3].link.slug,
          url: data.allPrismicSlider.nodes[0].data.slider[3].link.slug,
          src: data.allPrismicSlider.nodes[0].data.slider[3].image.url,
          alt: data.allPrismicSlider.nodes[0].data.slider[3].alternative_text,
        }
      ]
      return (
        <Slider {...settings}>
          {slides.map(slide => <Link to={`projects/${slide.url}`}><div key={slide.uid}><img src={slide.src} alt={slide.alt}/></div></Link>)}
        </Slider>
      )
    }
```

As you can see there are different links for each slide, however whenever the slide changes it seems that the top slide is always on top and the opacity is changed. I have attempted to follow this fix: https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/1400 however it didn't seem to fix the error.

Any advice would be hugely helpful.

Thank you.

Edit: Code sandbox as requested - https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-margulis-847rn?file=/src/components/gallery.js

Comment: try adding `key` prop in `Link` component.

Comment: @Chandan This didn't fix the error

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your css:

```
.slick-slide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-slide.slick-active {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

This worked for me.

Comment: As simple as this answer 

Answer (score 0):

The [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) value should be used in the iterable wrapper, not in the child since it's used by React to detect which element has changed.

```
    <Slider {...settings}>
      {slides.map(slide => <Link key={slide.uid} to={`projects/${slide.url}`}><div><img src={slide.src} alt={slide.alt}/></div></Link>)}
    </Slider>
```

From the docs:

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are
> removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give
> the elements a stable identity

Comment: Can you provide a CodeSandbox?

Comment: I have added a CodeSandbox

Comment: The sandbox doesn't seem to compile due to lack of the slider packages (I have tried installing the package)

Comment: I see, come back when it's fixed and try to add edit permissions please :)